# curl_exec is not working

Tags: php, windows, curl

I have this piece of code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $page_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 
  'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);

$header[] = "Accept: text/html, text/*";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

$html = curl_exec($ch) or die('111');
curl_close($ch);

 echo $html;
 exit('1');
```

I have windows with latest version of Xampp installed with curl enabled.

When I run the code it returns `111` without any errors.
I was expecting it to return the page content and `1`

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: Try `var_dump` instead of `echo`, you might see more relevant stuff there...

Comment: show us what is on `$page_url`

Comment: You are not even trying to capture any curl errors, instead you just `die(111)`.  You should investigate what sort of error you are having.  See the link from @MattS above. You may also want to check that `curl_init()` is not returning `false`.

Comment: with `$html = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error());` in show a blank page..

Comment: "CURL is not working for me" -> "Why? Are you not paying him enough?" - My thoughts exactly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like the example from the manual:

```
if(($html = curl_exec($ch)) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    die('111');
}
curl_close($ch);
echo $html;
exit('1');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Answer (score 1):

Don't die with a fixed error message. Try

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) {
   die(curl_error($ch));
}
```

instead. have curl tell you WHY it failed, instead of just spitting out some pointless `111` text.